# Binary Search Tree (Python) not showing result

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

I'm somewhat new to Python and need help with an issue I'm facing. I'm trying to make a binary search tree. I've written a code and it works, but won't show any result (printed values). I can't figure out what the issue might be. Here is the entire code:

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self, value):

        self.value = value

        self.left_child = None

        self.right_child = None

class binary_search_tree:

    def __init__(self):

        self.root_node = None

    def insert(self, value, curr_node):

        if self.root_node == None:

            self.root_node == node(value)

        elif self.root_node < value:

            if self.right_child == None:

                self.right.child = value

            else:

                curr_node == self.right_child

                if curr_node < value:

                    curr_node.right_child = node(value)

                elif curr_node > value:

                    curr_node.left_child = node(value)

                else:

                    print("Error! Value Already Exists!")

        elif self.root_node > value:

            if self.left_child == None:

                self.left.child = value

            else:

                curr_node == self.left_child

                if curr_node < value:

                    curr_node.right_child = node(value)

                elif curr_node > value:

                    curr_node.left_child = node(value)

                else:

                    print("Error! Value Already Exists!")

        else:

            print("Error! Value Already Exists!")

def fill_Tree(tree, num_elems = 100, max_int = 1000):

    from random import randint

    for x in range (num, elems):

        curr_elem = randint(0, max_int)

        tree.insert(curr_elem)

        return tree
```

I have made a class Node to handle the nodes and a function insert that helps to insert the values. It check for the root node. If its there, it moves onto the leaf based on the values. If not, it adds the value as the root. The program keeps on checking for values and nodes and their differences (less than, greater than etc), just the ways a tree is supposed to function. The program executes, but nothing shows up. Not sure what I'm doing wrong though.

Any sort of help would be appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post an example of how you run the code and the output? I'm assuming the indentation is an artifact of pasting your code into stackoverflow... but yeah, might want to fix that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Currently, your insertion method is assigning values to the left or right children of the *root*, not traveling to a depth beyond those two nodes, should a value smaller than the left child or greater than the right child be found. Instead, create one class to store the value, left, and right child, along with the necessary insertion method. To determine if a value exists in the tree, it is cleaner to utilize `__getitem__` with recursion:

```
def check_val(f): 
  def wrapper(cls, _val):
    if _val in cls.__class__.seen:
       raise ValueError(f"'{_val}' already in '{cls.__class__.__name__}'")
    return f(cls, _val)
  return wrapper

class Tree:
  seen = []
  def __init__(self, value=None):
    self.left = None
    self.value = value
    self.right = None
  def __lt__(self, _node):
    return self.value < getattr(_node, 'value', _node)
  @check_val
  def insert_val(self, _val):
    if self.value is None:
      self.value = _val
      self.__class__.seen.append(_val)
    else:
      if _val < self.value:
        if self.left is None:
           self.left = Tree(_val)
           Tree.seen.append(_val)
        else:
           self.left.insert_val(_val)
      else:
        if self.right is None:
           self.right = Tree(_val)
           Tree.seen.append(_val)
        else:
           self.right.insert_val(_val)
  def __getitem__(self, val):
     if self.value == val:
        return True
     if val < self.value:
        return getattr(self.left, '__getitem__', lambda _:False)(val)
     return getattr(self.right, '__getitem__', lambda _:False)(val)
  @classmethod
  def load_tree(cls, size = 10):
    _t = cls()
    import random
    for _ in range(size):
      _t.insert_val(random.randint(1, 100))
    return _t
```

To run:

```
t = Tree.load_tree()
print(t.__class__.seen)
#[82, 94, 33, 59, 73, 72, 96, 14, 58, 67]
for i in t.__class__.seen:
   assert t[i]
print('all cases passed')
```

Output:

```
'all cases passed'
```

Answer (score 0):

If that is your entire code, and if the input and execution is perfect, it would not show any result, **because you are not printing any result**.

You don't have an apparent main function to create an object of the `class binar_search_tree`.
The print statements that you have are **only when there is an error**. If everything works perfectly, your code doesn't print anything
You would need a method that can display the the tree

Comment: Hi.

There seems to be an easier way of implementing this. I found it at this link:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search-tree-set-1-search-and-insertion/